# Filtering words containing certain characters from a list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of words and a list of letters:

```
list = ["clyde","tool","ball","window"]
letters = ["c","t"]
```

I want to filter the first list by removing the word if it has any letters from the second list.

```
list = ["ball","window"]
```

Comment: Please share your current progress(code you have written)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `all()` to only retain words that do not have any letters that appear in `letters` (as an aside, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the `list` builtin):

```py
data = ["clyde","tool","ball","window"]
letters = ["c","t"]

result = list(filter(lambda x: all(c not in x for c in letters), data))

# Prints ['ball', 'window']
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `set` objects makes this pretty straight forward (and is the only solution so far which doesn't require iterating over the letters of each word using Python -- `set.intersection()` defers to the underlying C code to iterate over each letter):

```py
words = ["clyde", "tool", "ball", "window"]
letters = {"c", "t"}  # a set object

filtered_words = [word for word in words if not letters.intersection(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to understand code example

```
words_list = ["clyde","tool","ball","actor","window"]
letters = ["c","t"]
final_list=[]
# loop for each word in main list
for word in words_list:
    #check for each letter if present in restricted letters
    for letter in word:
        if letter in letters:
            break
    else:
        final_list.append(word)

print(final_list)
```

Comment: You could use a [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to make it so that you are accumulating valid words, as opposed to accumulating words to remove, which requires iterating twice (once to identify words to remove, once to remove them). To do so, add an `else` clause at the same indentation level as the inner `for` loop, and inside it, append `word` to `elements_to_keep`, and then in the `if letter in letters` statement, keep only the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using List Comprehensions，like this：

```
lst = ["clyde","tool","ball","window"]
letters = ["c","t"]

res = [data for data in lst if all(item not in data for item in letters)]
print(res)
```

Please note that it is better not to have variables with the same name as keywords in python,so I changed the list to lst